# SFDX - Lightning Web Components trailhead issue - Scratch Orgs being created as Sandboxes

Tags: lightning, trailhead, scratch-org

I'm working my way through the "Lightning Web Components Basics" trailhead and I've been directed to the following resource:

https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc#installing-e-bikes-using-salesforce-dx

As part of that, we need to create scratch orgs. I'm following the correct command:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ebikes
```

However, the orgs that are being created from my dev hub are marked as "Sandbox" in the top right-hand corner of the screen and seem to have Sandbox cs urls:

```
https://connect-efficiency-3392-dev-ed.cs87.my.salesforce.com/
```

[image]

Additionally, the orgs also seem to be stuck in Classic, so I can't progress.

I've updated to the latest versions of the SFDX CLI and plug-ins, so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

I'm expecting the scratch orgs to be in Lightning by default. However, I've turned on Lightning in the orgs where I can, ensured that my user is a Lightning user etc. Nonetheless, there's no option for my user to switch into Lightning.

Comment: Scratch Orgs are different than regular Sandboxes. When you say those are getting created as *Sandbox*, how are you creating those, and that how are you differentiating that those are sandbox and not scratch org?

Comment: @JayantDas - I've clarified in my original post. I'm creating Scratch orgs using the standard command. However, the orgs are marked as sandboxes and have sandbox CS urls

Comment: Salesforce defines orgs as basically one of three types: Developer, Sandbox, and Production. Scratch orgs fall in the Sandbox category, and behave similarly to sandboxes (but without Change Sets). As far as being stuck in Classic, you should be able to go in to Setup and enable Lightning, just like you would in a new Production org. Without knowing more about your situation, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: Some folks, including me, have experienced issues recently with new scratch orgs being "stuck" in Classic showing a My Domain-related error message. In my experience, the issue is transitory and resolves within 10 minutes. Others seem to have had more issues.

Comment: @sfdcfox -I've enabled lightning in the orgs, but it seems to make no difference. That's why I'm confused. What additional information would be useful?

Comment: Now that you posted the screenshot, I am thinking the culprit is Internet Explorer. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note from the "dev-ed" in the URL these are technically Developer orgs, but yet also located on Sandbox instances. This is a combination you don't normally see with non-scratch Developer orgs (which are located on Production instances).

Anyway this is not an anomaly - this is how Developer scratch orgs look for everyone.

The lack of Lightning, well that's a bit more mysterious.

EDIT 1: I tried creating two fresh scratch orgs, one as "Developer" in project-scratch-def and the other as "Partner Developer". The Developer org opened straight to Lightning. The Partner Developer org opened to Classic with the error:

> An error has occurred in the following section: [Exception,
>   DomainNotPropagated]. Salesforce.com has been notified of this error.
>   An error has occurred in the following section: [Exception,
>   DomainNotPropagated_desc]. Salesforce.com has been notified of this
>   error.

However after a few minutes I was able to refresh and get Lightning.

EDIT 2: Yikes is that Internet Explorer? No wonder. Lightning is not supported in IE. Change your default browser to Chrome, Firefox or Edge and you'll have more success opening the org into Lightning.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just came back here to say so, but you got there first. Apologies. My defaults got changed by my IT team and I was thrown by the Sandbox labeling. Apologies all.